# Would this design be considered an FIR filter?

Tags: vhdl, verilog

If you added registers, or delays, in parallel to the registers shown in the diagram, would that be considered an FIR filter?

In this case, it would be adding 4 additional registers: 1 between the first multiplier (b0) and the first adder, and 1 register between each set of adders.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, we are focused on programming related questions. Your question might be better suited to another of the stackexchange sites. Try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To Clifford: Yes. Actually it already is a FIR filter. Your picture matches the one at the Wikipedia page on Finite impulse response Filters.

There are a number of ways to code the filter in sythesizable Verilog which would give a you faster implementation in less area; or smaller area and slower execution.

To Simon: this question is tagged as Verilog and VHDL question, so it does straddle the line between programming and hardware.